# "Извините пожалуйста" разделяется запятой?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Что с ней, извините пожалуйста, случилось?

Как мне кажется, в данном предложении "извините пожалуйста" является цельным выражением и поэтому не требует разделения, но так ли это на самом деле?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Статистика. В Нацкорпусе 391 из 414 вхождений содержит запятую. Остальное — диалоги на форумах и следующие отрывки (скорее всего, пунктуация авторская или запятая пропала при оцифровке):

> ― Если это называется «замахнулся»… ― Ну **извини пожалуйста**. Очень уж ты неудачно под горячую руку… [Олег Дивов. Выбраковка (1999)]
>
> ― **Извините пожалуйста**, это Агентство Социальной Безопасности, ― сказал Гусев, демонстрируя значок дверному глазку. [Олег Дивов. Выбраковка (1999)]
>
> ― **Извини пожалуйста**, я был неправ. Видишь ли, Пэ, ты ведь не ходил дежурным по отделению, верно? [Олег Дивов. Выбраковка (1999)]
>
> ― **Извини пожалуйста**. Со мной тоже бывает. [Олег Дивов. Молодые и сильные выживут (1998)]
>
> ― «Но если уж касаться социальной проблемы, то, ― и дьявольский хохот, ― **извините пожалуйста**: нет ― не по Бердяеву, не по Булгакову, жалкие путаники! [Андрей Белый. Начало века (1930)]
>
> Мне теперь ясно ― до ужаса: я был ― один, как перст, а один ― в поле не воин; но я тешил себя социальной фикцией, будто бы есть какие-то друзья, которые меня тут именно понимают; меня тут именно не хотели понять: ни Владимиров, ни С. М. Соловьев, не говоря о товарищах по курсу; и не понимали впоследствии: Мережковские, Блок, Брюсов и Вячеслав Иванов; отсюда ― постоянная тема себя снижения именно в этом пункте и добровольный ракурс пространственных, так сказать, представлений о символизме в плоскостных проекциях ― таких-то для Брюсова, таких-то для Блока; иногда этот вынужденный подгиб себя под других, от нежелания другими выпрямить во весь рост проблему, переживался как нечто изнуряющее до крайности; и почти ― унизительное; отсюда этот тон мой ко многим с «**извините пожалуйста**» и с «так сказать, согласен»....  [Андрей Белый. Почему я стал символистом и почему я не перестал им быть во всех фазах моего идейного и художественного развития (1928)]
>
> Я знаю: ты такая нравственная, чистая, но… ты вот была сегодня у Ревизанова… Раньше ― **извини пожалуйста**! ― ты не бывала у него? [А. В. Амфитеатров. Отравленная совесть (1882-1893)]

Answer (score 5):

1) **Что с ней, извините, пожалуйста, случилось?**

В правилах нет цельного выражения "извините пожалуйста". При встрече двух вводных слов **они оба обособляются.**

2) В этом предложении можно использовать тире, то есть оформить фразу  ***извините, пожалуйста*** как вставную конструкцию:

Что с ней ― **извините, пожалуйста** ― случилось?

3)Варианты с отсутствием запятой  ― **это ненормированная авторская пунктуация.**

4) Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122

3. При сочетании двух вводных слов между ними ставится запятая:

**Чего доброго, пожалуй,** и женится, из умиления души (Дост.);  **Стало быть, по-вашему,** физическим трудом должны заниматься все без исключения? (Ч.);  **Признаться, право,** было б жаль мне опечалить их [отца и мать] (Л.); Не надо нас мужикам-то, **не ровён час, пожалуй,** и в шею накладут (М.-С.).

5) **Пример:** А сейчас, **извините, пожалуйста,** я на рынок пойду. [Юрий Казаков. В первый раз попал я в Печоры... (1963)]

Comment: В Вашем примере обособление неоспоримо, но вот что насчёт восклицательных предложений, в которых данное выражение показывает некое недовольство?

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, какой храбрый! Но это же не ваш случай, совсем другое значение. (Употр. для усиления междометных слов, для выражения удивления, возмущения, негодования, иронии).

Comment: Возможно, смысл предложения был понятен неправильно. Здесь подразумевается не забота, а, допустим, гнев, недовольство.

Comment: Существуют только междометные выражения "скажите пожалуйста, скажите на милость"

Comment: @ЛизаЗапорожец Ещё есть интересное цельное (фразеологическое) выражение **извини-подвинься (извините-подвиньтесь).** https://phraseology.academic.ru/4989/Извините-подвиньтесь

Comment: То есть в моём случае обособление обязательно, даже несмотря на отсутствие интонационной паузы?

Comment: Запятая ставится в соответствии с грамматическим принципом. Дело в том, что не каждую грамматическую структуру можно выразить с помощью интонации (интонационные возможности имеют ограничения). В частности это касается вводных слов, когда они входят в сложное предложение. В вашем предложении такая же ситуация: оба вводных слова приходится объединять в одну фразу и произносить без паузы.